# What do these Xcode 4 debugger icons mean?

Tags: icons, xcode4

I haven't been able to find what these Xcode icons mean.  Some you can deduce (cup icon is cocoa, person icon is your code) but other's are more mysterious.

[image: Xcode Debugger Navigator]
[image: Xcode Debugger Navigator]
[image: Xcode Debugger Navigator]

UPDATE 1:

I was able to find the icon files under:

> .../Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/Resources

There's a total of 13 different icons and they are all clearly labeled. In the screenshot that I posted we have:

- Person icon is User
- Mug icon is AppKit (or UIKit)
- Briefcase icon is Frameworks
- Gear icon is System
- Morse code icon is Foundation
- Spider web looking icon is Web

Update 2:

A while back I wrote a blog post that's easier to read:
http://jlmendezbonini.com/2013/03/27/Xcode-4-debugger-icons.html

Update 3:

Looks like Apple finally documented it in the [Process View Display](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH8-SW19)
 section.  Here's a link to the image:

[image: Strackframe icon group]

Comment: Your images aren't loading for me. Can you move them to Imgur.com instead?

Comment: They loaded fine for me the first time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon means, in general, assembly for which you don't have debugging symbols. Not your code (the person icon), not public, top-level Cocoa code (the mug), not Framework/library code (the suitcase) but plain old assembly.

I don't think this is documented anywhere (I haven't seen it) but it seems to hold true for all the tests I've done.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick screen shot of the folder mentioned. The names explain the meaning of each icon. This is from xcode 5 beta 2. [image]