# Category Icons in Xcode Instruments

Tags: xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

What do the icons in the categories column mean?

[image]

I'd like to add to this question regarding a more modern UI of Xcode Instruments 7.2. The image is a portion of a Time Profiling Instrument Details pane, specifically Call Tree selection output. What is the icon at the bottom of the 2nd image that looks like a house with 3 windows that is followed by a hex number? This icon is also in the old Instruments UI (grey highlight above). Could this be an unavailable symbol?

[image]

Comment: Can you hover over them in order to find that out?

Comment: When you hover over them nothing happens, right-clickking is still no help

Comment: Wha version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Technically this a screen shot of instruments: the icons are the same for Xcode 3 & Xcode 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category icons show which part of the system the call was to. There doesn't seem to be a description of each icon anywhere, but the symbols are pretty clear, for example a **cup** means Cocoa, a **gearwheel** system libraries and a **little person** means your code.

When hovering your mouse over a category icon, the library is shown in the tooltip (at least in Xcode 4):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question (What is the icon at the bottom of the 2nd image that looks like a house with 3 windows that is followed by a hex number? This icon is also in the old Instruments UI (grey highlight above). Could this be an unavailable symbol?). The icon that looks like a house with windows refers to a code symbol that is uncategorized or generic (whatever that means). Now I have to figure out why the code in the profiling data is coming up as uncategorized and not user code or system code.

Here is a good page to ID the rest of the Xcode [icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077445/what-do-these-xcode-4-debugger-icons-mean).

Comment: This post is confusing. What question (of yours) did you answer?