# XCode - CallStack icons

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, callstack

What do the callstack symbols indicate? I know a little bit about how to analyze callstack but I never understood the purpose of these symbols.

[image]

Comment: The coffee mug is Cocoa, the silhouette is user code, and I'm not too sure about the rest. I never considered it more than spiffy presentation.

Comment: Would like to know those other ones myself.

Comment: Pls refer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077445/what-do-these-xcode-4-debugger-icons-mean